# How to convert dataframe into sparse matrix?

Tags: r, vectorization, sparse-matrix

How to convert dataframe into sparse matrix? 
For example, please see below the `dataframe`. Need to see this `dataframe` as a whole factor with levels 1~10. Convert levels into 10 columns. Convert 0 to 1 based on what factor it has it each Row in V1~V4. Which will become something like the `Expected Outcome`.

Take Row 1 in `Expected Outcome` for example, column `No1`, `No2`, `No5`, `No8` == 1 because V1~V4 has the number 1,8,2,5.

**Update:** Have tried solution [Create Sparse Matrix from a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207850/create-sparse-matrix-from-a-data-frame/26208307#26208307)  , cannot get it to match my `Expected Outcome`

**Dataframe**

```
    V1   V2   V3   V4  
1   1    8    2    5
2   6    7    9    3
3   6    2    3    2
4   5    8    9    10
5   4    3    5    1
6   3    9    1    10
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
    V1   V2   V3   V4   No1 No2 No3 No4 No5 No6 No7 No8 No9 No10 
1   1    8    2    5     1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
2   6    7    9    3     0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0
3   6    2    3    4     0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0  
4   5    8    9    10    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1
5   4    3    5    1     1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
6   3    9    1    10    1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

Comment: There was a question like yours here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26208307/4525807. Try those solutions out.

Comment: @JellisHeRo I've tried it, cannot make it something like my `Expected Outcome` , that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Is this the question?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: It won't let me answer the question because it is locked but all you need to do is: 
`dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,8,2,5,6,7,9,3,6,2,3,2,5,8,9,10,4,3,5,1,3,9,1,10), byrow = T, ncol = 4)) ; sparse <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = nrow(dat), ncol = max(dat))) ; for(i in 1:nrow(dat)) sparse[i, as.matrix(dat[i,])] <- 1 ; colnames(sparse) <- paste0("No",full); cbind(data.frame(dat), sparse)`

Comment: @EvanFriedland Thanks for the reply, I got this `Error in paste0("No", full) : object 'full' not found` after executing the codes.

Comment: Oh woops, instead of full just use `1:max(dat)`

Comment: `dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,8,2,5,6,7,9,3,6,2,3,2,5,8,9,10,4,3,5,1,3,9,1,10), byrow = T, ncol = 4)) ; sparse <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = nrow(dat), ncol = max(dat))) ; for(i in 1:nrow(dat)) sparse[i, as.matrix(dat[i,])] <- 1 ; cbind(dat, setNames(sparse, paste0("No",1:max(dat))))`

Comment: What if the data is too big?  eg: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 165.5 Gb`  when executing `sparse <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = nrow(dat), ncol = max(dat))) `